# Elegant solution to no javascript

Tags: jquery, css, replace, noscript

So I have created a  jquery dropdown which looks nice but now I need to handle the noscript users. With Javascript turned off my div is still there and is also displays the alternative bog standard select box.

I am looking for an elegant solution to remove all jquery enalbled content, (with css?) and replace them with more baisc HTML.

Comment: Some code or better explanation of what you have will help us to help you.

Comment: Or you could go the other route and let the JavaScript generate the markup necessary for it to work properly when JavaScript is enabled. Ensure it works without JavaScript first, then enhance the experience with JavaScript.

Comment: Instead of dealing it in the same view , i would suggest you to check on server side if the user javascript is ENABLED on their browsers, based on that redirect them to approriate seperate views.i-e one with JS , one without JS.

Comment: @Fur server side code can't detect if browser has JS enabled or not.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, no but a simple JS-initiated (or JS-enriched) request can be used (requires round-trip).

Answer (score 6):

You are approaching the problem from the wrong direction. You should start with basic HTML and then apply progressive enhancements through javascript/jQuery/etc. Using that model you will always have the fall back of 'javascript disabled' with a workable interface.

Trying to work backward from a 'bells and whistles' interface is doubly hard.

If there are additional HTML entities required for your enhanced interface then the best thing is to set them to "display: none" and reveal them using javascript/jQuery/etc.

Comment: A few resources: [Progressive enhancement on WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) (general), [ALA: Understanding Progressive Enhancement](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement/) (the theory), and [Progressive Enhancement: What It Is, And How To Use It?](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/22/progressive-enhancement-what-it-is-and-how-to-use-it/) (examples).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to go other way round. First you develop the page without jquery content. The page should use just standard html elements. And then you use jQuery to extend them(eg. change standard dropdown with jQuery one).

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Lazarus.  To help you with your drop-down, you can use css `":hover"` to achieve some hiding and revealing using no JS.